# Angular 2.4.10 Platform-Browser-Dynamic Problems

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2.4.10 to build a project and when I start the project with "nom start" command, on Firefox browser console, project gives me this error:

```
Error loading npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js/index.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.10",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.10",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

main.ts file:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

What is solution for this problem?

Comment: Delete the node_modules folder and re run **npm install**